Using the key attribute to control component refresh in vue failed
I need to click a button to modify the key value of the component through the bound function, and I find that the key value has changed, but the component is not unloaded for re-rendering.
I checked a lot of information on the Internet, found that they are so to achieve page refresh, this problem has been troubled for a long time.
I hope there are kind people to guide me how to correctly use the key attribute to complete the page refresh.
enter image description here
<template>
  <!-- 路由组件出口 -->
  <!-- v-slot可以获取当前渲染的组件以及路由信息 -->
  <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
    <transition name="fade">
      <!-- 渲染home一级路由的子路由 -->
      <component :is="Component" :key="refreshContent"/>
    </transition>
  </router-view>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import emitter from "@/utils/emitter";
import { onUnmounted, onMounted } from "vue";


let refreshContent = 0

emitter.on('refresh_content', () => {
  refreshContent += 1
  console.log(refreshContent)
})

onMounted(() => {
  console.log('load')
})

onUnmounted(() => {
  emitter.off('refresh_content')
  console.log('unload')
})

</script>

<style scoped>
.fade-enter-from {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0)
}

.fade-enter-to {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.fade-enter-active {
  transform: all 0.5s;
}
</style>```

I need to click a button to modify the key value of the component through the bound function, and I find that the key value has changed, but the component is not unloaded for re-rendering.
I checked a lot of information on the Internet, found that they are so to achieve page refresh, this problem has been troubled for a long time.
I hope there are kind people to guide me how to correctly use the key attribute to complete the page refresh.

I think you want refreshContent to be reactive, i.e. a ref

Yes, I do. I make refreshContent responsive, but it also does not trigger component uninstallation, i.e. does not trigger the onUnmounted lifecycle hook.
If the key value changes, vue thinks the component is new and triggers the onUnmounted lifecycle hook to complete the refresh.

Specifically modified the following code
let refreshContent = ref(0)
refreshContent.value += 1

You need to set refreshContent to responsive data, such as refreshContent = ref(0); refreshContent.value += 1;

Yes, I do. I make refreshContent responsive, but it also does not trigger component uninstallation, i.e. does not trigger the onUnmounted lifecycle hook.

The purpose of refreshContent is to ensure that <component :is="Component" :key="refreshContent"/>  is re-rendered, so that every time refreshContent changes, Component is re-rendered. Changes in refreshContent will re-render the component, but will not cause the component to be destroyed.Therefore, it will not trigger the onUnmounted

Wow, thanks to my friend's explanation, the effect I want to achieve is to refresh the page, which means that using the key attribute allows vue to re-render the component without uninstalling it, thus achieving the refresh effect.

As for why I don't feel the page refresh, is it because my page currently has very little text and is not dynamically displayed based on the data returned by the server interface?

So when I click the button to change the key value, vue has already finished re-rendering the component, but vue is smart enough to detect that the internal data of the component has not changed and uses the original data.

I also want to ask another question, if my refreshContent does not use the reactive type, my refreshContent is written inside the component, so as long as the component does not uninstall the refreshContent data, it can always be changed, and the page can always be refreshed, right?

Thank you my friend, through your answer, inspired me to try to find the answer, I through their own practice. I found that a change in the key value caused this to re-render or uninstall. Why didn't I trigger the onUnmounted hook before?

This is because the onUnmounted hook monitors the current component, but the component that I wrote the onUnmounted hook contains only the code of the dynamically displayed component, so the dynamically displayed component will not be unloaded, and the onUnmounted needs to be written in the specific displayed component.

Yes, I did. The onUnmounted hook was triggered. Also, I found that if refreshContent is not reactive, it will not refresh the page. Why is that?
